# Bootstrap Table Export and Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the table refresh and export as shown as the first example here: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/extensions.html but it seems like my codes are not working. The plugin I use are tableExport and bootstrap-table-export.js. This is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/ug0hycdg/

Table pagination only works if I include this script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#pageTables').dataTable();
    });
```

but the table should be in pagination even without this script.

Any idea why it won't work?

I've added the button:

```
    <button onClick ="$('#pageTables').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});"> Save </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to import [the source](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) of bootstrap-table, the jsFiddle example: jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/147/.

Hope to help you.